# how to use wireshark in a bash script

Tags: bash

I am writing a linux bash script, in which i want to capture on eth0 for some duration and save it to some file. Also i want that after the capture is over wireshark should close and my rest of the commands in the script should execute in sequence. How i can achieve it. A very simple example i am trying is given below. But it is not coming out of the wireshark to the main script. Please help me to achieve this.

```
#!/bin/bash

xterm -e wireshark -i eth0 -a duration:20 -k > ./capture1

sleep 10

echo " came back to main window "

xterm killall -9 wireshark
```

Comment: it seems that backgrounding wireshark should do what you're looking for. see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15985/non-blocking-bash-command

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am also now trying backgrounding only. But somehow i am not able to save my capture data to a file. I have open a capture using wireshark using command : sudo wireshark -i eth0 -Q -a duration:50 -k &
and now i am trying to copy the capture to a file named capture1.cap using command :  dumpcap -i eth0 -w capture1.cap 
But it gives me error on the second one as : The file to which the capture would be saved ("capture1.cap") could not be opened: Permission denied.
But i don't see any permission issue with the file capture1. Can you tell me what i am missing. Please ....

Comment: please edit your question rather than fill up comment areas with hard to read psuedo-code. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **tshark**

```
echo "starting capture for 20 seconds"

tshark -i eth0 -a duration:20 -w capture1.pcap

echo "done"
```

tshark is the text version of wireshark.. you don't have to worry about it trying to do anything with the GUI

Comment: I have tried this and i got below error :                           tshark: The file to which the capture would be saved ("capture1.pcap") could not be opened: Permission denied.